# How can I use a Logitech Driving Force GT in GTA5 & NFS on PS3?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v, controllers

I've bought a Logitech Driving Force GT for PS3. mostly for playing GTA 5 with it.

However it didn't work at all in GTA5, the Speed Brake Pedal And Accelerator aren't being recognised.

Does anyone know how to get this working in GTA 5?

Here is a picture of the device:

[image: Logitech Driving Force GT]

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why NFS doesn't work with the wheel, but I DO know that GTA V doesn't support using the wheel. On the PC they've made a hack that allows it ( https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/manual-transmission-ikt ) but I don't think that it's likely on PS3. Sorry.